# Unable to resize spinner in tablelayout

Tags: android-layout, android-spinner, android-tablelayout, android-layout-weight

Running Android Studio 1.0.2 and am having problems resizing a spinner.
I would like the layout to be 50/50 on a single line.

text : spinner.

Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="country_arrays">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>New Zealand</item>
        <item>India</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tblSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSelect"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:text="Select item:"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:entries="@array/country_arrays"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Currently the spinner is taking up about 90% of the width with the textview 10%.

Comment: Try to change `android:layout_width` to `fill_parent`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That did it. Been trying to get it working for hours :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change android:layout_width to fill_parent

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your layout width from wrap_content to an actual width.  It will be specific your layout and platform so use with care.

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#33777777"
    android:layout_margin="1dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView\nthis" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        a`ndroid:layout_width="30dip"`
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</TableRow>
```